# How to handle js functions when we use markup-based DOM-ready execution

Tags: javascript, json, unobtrusive-javascript

Sorry for the long read, but it would be nice if you can share your thoughts anyway. :)

So.. the technique is described in Paul Irish's blogpost here -
http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution and then extended by Jason Garber here - 
http://viget.com/inspire/extending-paul-irishs-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution .

The main idea is to have a json object that would contain all of you code that is supposed to be executed when a particular page (controller and/or view) is loaded (on DOM-ready).

The object would look something like:

```
APP = {
  controller1 : {
    view10: function(){ ... },
    view11: function(){ ... }
  },
  controller2: {
    view20: function() {...},
    view21: function() {...}
  }
}
```

Then you change your `<body>` into

```
<body data-controller="controller_name" data-action="view_name">
```

and then with some JS goodies when the DOM is ready there is an automatic call to `APP.controller_name.view_name()`.

This is super awesome because you can put all of your to-be-executed-on-DOM-ready scripts on one place and these scripts are executed without additional code.

**And now to the actual question:** 
What to do with the other JS functions for a particular controller or view/page that are not supposed to be executed when the DOM is ready but when an event occur (e.g. onclick="someFunction()"?

It would be really nice if these functions are within the appropriate `APP.controller_name` namespace because that would help maintain the code. And with that said, I'm currently changing my APP object into something like:

```
APP = {
  controller1 : {
    view10: function(){ ... },
    view11: function(){ ... },
    extraStuff10: function: () {...},
    extraStuff11: function: () {...}
  },
  controller2: {
    view20: function() {...},
    view21: function() {...},
    extraStuff20: function: () {...}
  }
}
```

And this is all good - `APP.controller1.view10()` is executed automatically and you can call `APP.controller1.extraStuff10()` when you need it afterwards. But there one *serious* drawback for that structure - view10() and extraStuff10() have absolutely identical structure so you can't tell whether extraStuff10() is a function that is waiting to be executed when an event occur OR if there is an actual view/page that is called extraStuff and the content of that function will be executed when the page is loaded.

I'm thinking of changing the function view10() into an object that contains init() function (and we'll place the script-for-DOM-ready inside) like that:

```
APP = {
  controller1 : {
    view10: {
      init(): function(){ ... }
    },
    extraFunction10: function: () {...}
  }
}
```

This will give clear separation of the DOM-ready functions and the other functions but I'm wondering if that is the best way to accomplish that stuff... Any ideas?

Comment: I've seen a PHP architecture modelled on a similar system. Seems to me you'd want to have a pretty heavy-duty thing going to justify this approach in js :)

Comment: That's actually hard to tell and really depends on the specific project. I currently have a few libraries that are twice the size of my main js file. And I'm not even counting jQuery (which is way bigger than my whole `app` code).

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice pattern, but I would recommend splitting things up a bit as the one-file-that-rules-them-all approach will soon become unwieldy. What happens when your app grows to 50 pages? You end up with a monster file to edit which has to be loaded in it's entirety for very page, increasing both download and parsing time.

Smaller JS library files loaded dynamically depending on which page is accessed would work well. You can then attach functions to the APP global namespace, so they can be reused between pages. Your controller code stays light as it would then just attach a simple onclick or whatever so that the already-loaded library stuff is triggered.

Moving towards using a requirements manager for loading the libraries in the right order may help with this e.g. http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: Our JavaScript was previously in a lot of different files (like what you suggest, but not very well structured) but that was not the optimal way for us to manage the code so we decided to put everything in one place so that we always know where to look for a particular page related code or function.

And in case the code for APP.controllerX namespace become too big at some point, we can always put it in controllerX.js and define `app.controllerX = {..}` there. The download time won't be a problem because everything is cached and the parsing shouldn't take long because the file is not that big.

Comment: And we are using Minify for serving and combining JavaScript files because it works with PHP on the server (opposed to requirejs).

Comment: Fair enough. I'd certainly agree with having a separate app.controllerX.js. Am I right in thinking that you have a lot of page specific code? I've solved similar issues in the past by breaking the pages into small reusable sections, each with its own viewX.php that includes viewX.js, but maybe this is not feasible? Bear in mind that whilst caching and parsing will be fine on the desktop, tablets and mobile will often have a very small cache and take a lot longer to parse stuff, so it can still be an issue.

Comment: Lots of page specific code? Not really, our page specific code (for DOM-ready execution) is usually less than 1KB per page and we also have 1-2KB of additional functions per controller (each controller is serving 3-6 pages) on average. It's not much and that's the reason for wanting to put everything in one place (and not as separate files).

`app.controllerX.js` is definitely an option but not for now.